# Distributional derivative of $\sin { (\pi|x|/2))} \chi_{\{|x|<2\}}$

Tags: real-analysis, distribution-theory, dirac-delta

I have to find the  first and the second distributional  derivative of the function :
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} \sin { (\pi|x|/2))}  \quad & |x| <2 \\ 0 \quad & |x| \geq 2 \end{cases}$$ 
  but I am not sure  if I am doing it  in the right way.

The first derivative should be
 $$ g'(x) = \cos { (\pi|x|/2))}\operatorname{sgn}(x) \pi/2 $$
because  $f(x)$ is a continuous function  with no jumps in any point so the delta does not appear.

The second derivative should be :

$$ g''(x) = - \sin { (\pi|x|/2))}[\operatorname{ sgn}(x)]^2 (\pi/2)^2 +    \delta _2   -\delta _{(-2)}   $$

I have never seen a distribution  with jumps in different points before, am I correct if I apply the delta in each of this points? Also I am not sure if the jump is $+1$ or $-1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distributional derivative of a piecewise smooth function consists of two terms:

- pointwise derivative, found as in calculus
- singular part: if $f$ is discontinuous at $a$, add $(f(a+)-f(a-))\delta_a$; this is done for each discontinuity.

You correctly found that $f'$ has no singular part. However, note that the formula for $f'$  should also say that it's zero when $|x|>2$.

The function $f'$ is discontinuous at *three* points: $-2,0,2$.

- at $-2$  the left limit is $0$, the right limit is $\pi/2$
- at $0$  the left limit is $-\pi/2$, the right limit is $\pi/2$
- at $ 2$  the left limit is $-\pi/2$, the right limit is $0$

So, the singular part of $f''$ is 
$$\frac{\pi}{2} (\delta_{-2} +2\delta_0 +\delta_2)$$
You found the continuous part of $f''$ correctly, but it can be simplified to 
$$- \sin { (\pi|x|/2))}  (\pi/2)^2$$
And again, $f''(x)$ is zero when $|x|>2$.

Comment: if I compute the fourier transform of $f''$ as a distribution do I have  to sum the fourier transform of the regular part  with the fourier transforms of those $\delta$?  initially  I thought it was  just $\hat f(k) (i2\pi k)^2 $ but now I think it is wrong

Comment: Yes, if you want to do it directly. But it may be easier to do what you thought initially: use a formula for $\widehat{f''}$ in terms of $\widehat{f}$.

Comment: Yes, they should both give the same result if your computation is correct. A nice thing about distributions is that some things that work for test functions automatically  work for distributions too, because one can pass both the derivatives and the Fourier hat onto the test function.

Comment: does the formula $\hat( f^m) = (i2 \pi k ) ^m \hat f $ imply the derivative  are  in the sense of distribution? because i thought  that formula was valid only for classic pointwise derivative. edit: ok i thing i got it, ty.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\norm}[1]{\left\vert\left\vert\, #1\,\right\vert\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\fermi\pars{x} \equiv
     \Theta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}\sin\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{x}}}$

---

\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\fermi'\pars{x}}&
=\delta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}\bracks{-\sgn\pars{x}}
\sin\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{x}}
+\Theta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}\cos\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{x}}
\,{\pi \over 2}\,\sgn\pars{x}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large{\pi \over 2}\,\Theta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}
\cos\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{x}}\sgn\pars{x}}
\\[1cm]\color{#66f}{\large\fermi''\pars{x}}&
={\pi \over 2}\,\delta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}\bracks{-\sgn\pars{x}}
\cos\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{x}}\sgn\pars{x}
\\[5mm]&+{\pi \over 2}\,\Theta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}
\bracks{-\sin\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{x}}
\,{\pi \over 2}\,\sgn\pars{x}}\sgn\pars{x}
\\[5mm]&+{\pi \over 2}\,\Theta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}
\cos\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{x}}\bracks{2\,\delta\pars{x}}
\\[5mm]&={\pi \over 2}\,\delta\pars{\verts{x} - 2}
-{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\Theta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}\sin\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{x}}
+\pi\,\delta\pars{x}
\\[5mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\pi\,\delta\pars{x} + {\pi \over 2}\,\delta\pars{x + 2}
+ {\pi \over 2}\,\delta\pars{x - 2}}
\\[5mm]&
\color{#66f}{\large\phantom{=}-{\pi^{2} \over 4}\,\Theta\pars{2 - \verts{x}}\sin\pars{{\pi \over 2}\,\verts{x}}}
\end{align}

Comment: What is that $\Theta$ ?

Comment: @Alucard $\Theta\left(\,x\,\right)$ is the [Heaviside Step Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function). Physicists usually use $\Theta$ instead of ${\rm H}$ to avoid confusion with 'Magnetic Field', 'Harmonic Number', 'Hamiltonian', etc...

Comment: i cannot understand in the last line why there is  $\pi/2 \delta(x+2) + \pi/2 \delta(x-2)$

Comment: @Alucard I use:
$$
\delta\left(\,{\rm g}\left(\,x\,\right)\,\right)
=\sum_{n}{\delta\left(\,x - x_{n}\,\right)\over
\left\vert\,{\rm g}'\left(\,x_{n}\,\right)\,\right\vert}
$$
where $\,{\rm g}\left(\,x_{n}\,\right) = 0$. With $\,{\rm g}\left(\,x\,\right)=\delta\left(\,2 - \left\vert\,x\right\vert\,\right)$ it becomes:
$$
\delta\left(\,2 - \left\vert\,x\right\vert\,\right)
={\delta\left(\,x + 2\,\right) \over \left\vert\,{\rm sgn}\left(\,x\,\right)\,\right\vert}
+
{\delta\left(\,x - 2\,\right) \over \left\vert\,{\rm sgn}\left(\,x\,\right)\,\right\vert}
$$

Comment: @Alucard ...which yields
$$
\delta\left(\,x + 2\,\right) + \delta\left(\,x - 2\,\right)
$$

Comment: do you know where   i can  find a step-by-step  proof  of this rule ?

Comment: @Alucard [Just here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function).